# Permutation in Block Ciphers

Tags: encryption, aes, algorithm

I was reading some e-books to understand the basics of block ciphers and how it works in AES. As i understood, Permutation plays a big part in AES and Block Ciphers,

Here is what i understood by permutation,

```
A permutation is an ordered arrangement of the elements of some set S
Let S = {a, b, c}
c, b, a is a permutation of S
b, c, a is a different permutation of S
```

Now, 
There was a power-point slide on Block ciphers i was reading and according to which,

[image]

Why did they call it a permutation, 
Could anyone please explain ?

Comment: Think "shuffling" of the same deck of cards, and how many variations in their order there might be - that's _permutations_. I.e. multiple arrangements of the same set of elements. The right image is not a permutation, because its _function of x_ `f(x)` adds and removes from to the topmost set. In our previous example of a deck of cards, you'd have to remove some, and replace them with cards from another deck to end up with the same number of cards that are not a permutation of a complete deck of cards. This is however not really a question on scope for [security.se]. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you have given S has a,b and c. It's permutation must have exactly the same number of elements of the same type. One **a**, one **b** and one **c**. In total it has to have 3 elements and order of elements can be different.

In the second example, x has these values:

- a **00**
- a **01**
- a **10**
- a **11**

It's permutation, f(x) can have these values with the same count. So the left f(x) is a permutation because it has a **00**,  a **01**, a **10** and a **11**. Right f(x) is NOT, because it has 2x **11**, a **01**, and a **10** which is different than the x values.